# iOS: UISegmentedControl VS UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

What are the best practices of using these controls ? The documentation is not very clear about when should these be used. They seem to be doing the same thing but in different ways. When should one use `UISegmentedControl` and when `UITabBarController` ?

Answer (score 4):

I think of it this way:
`UISegmentedControl` is for multiple options with a single view controller.
`UITabBarController` is for navigating between multiple view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

UISegmentedControl is used in a single view controller to manipulate different views. It is usually used to reload table view from different data sources based on each segment.

UITabBarController holds multiple view controllers which are loaded and user can switch between them by tapping on the tab.